# Kendo MultiSelect passando o placeholder como valor na pesquisa

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Tenho um formulário com um componente **Kendo UI MultiSelect** para **ASP.NET MVC / Razor**:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m.Ids)
                .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                .AutoBind(true)
                .MinLength(3)
                .Delay(500)
                .DataTextField("Value")
                .DataValueField("Key")
                .Placeholder("Please fill")
                .DataSource(
                    ds => ds.Read(
                        r => r.Action("FillMultiSelect", "ReportsController", new { companyId = IdentityManager.CompanyID, search = string.Empty })
                        ).ServerFiltering(true)
                )
            )
```

JavaScript para configuração do filtro:

```
var $ids = $("#Ids").data("kendoMultiSelect");

$ids.dataSource.transport.options.read.data = basicFilter($ids);

var basicFilter = function ($element) {
   return {
       companyId: self.form.getModel().CompanyId,
       search: $element.input.val()
   }
}
```

Quando eu digito o texto de pesquisa no campo "Ids", o parâmetro passado pra `Action` do **MVC** é o valor do ***placeholder*** do campo, e não o que foi digitado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que está errado no meu código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro estava na maneira de recuperar o valor digitado no `MultiSelect`. O correto é utilizar o array `filters` do objeto `filter` passado como parâmetro no evento `data`. O código JavaScript corrigido ficou assim:

```
window.global.setDatasourceTransportFilter($("#Ids"), "kendoMultiSelect", basicFilter);

var basicFilter = function (e) {
   return {
       companyId: self.form.getModel().CompanyId,
       search: e.filter && e.filter.filters[0] ? e.filter.filters[0].value : ""
   }
}
```